Swapping amplitudes of orthogonal components
Let $A\subset[2^n]$, $|A\rangle=\sum_{i\in A} |i\rangle$ and let $$|\psi\rangle =  \sqrt\frac{|A|}{2^n}|A\rangle - \sqrt\frac{2^n - |A|}{2^n} |A^\bot\rangle\,. $$
Is it possible to implement a unitary that swaps the amplitudes, i.e. such that $$U|\psi\rangle =  \sqrt\frac{|A|}{2^n}|A^\bot\rangle - \sqrt\frac{2^n - |A|}{2^n} |A\rangle\,?$$

Yes, unitaries map orthonormal bases to orthonormal bases.
As $|A\rangle$ and $|A^{\perp}\rangle$ are orthogonal they can be extended to an orthonormal basis on the space. Let's call such a basis $\{|\psi_i\rangle\}_{i=1}^d$ where $|\psi_1\rangle = |A\rangle$ and $|\psi_2\rangle = |A^{\perp}\rangle$. Now you can define
$$
U = |\psi_1\rangle \langle \psi_2| + |\psi_2\rangle \langle \psi_1| + \sum_{k=3}^d |\psi_k\rangle \langle \psi_k|
$$
which would implement your desired action. You can indeed check it is a unitary by checking $U^\dagger U = U U^\dagger = I$, using the properties of orthonormal bases.
Note, however, that this is far from a unique construction.

Thank you! Can it be specified in terms of $|\psi\rangle$, too? Let me clarify: instead of having terms $|A\rangle \langle A^\bot|$, can this be equivalently formulated in terms of psi and uniform superposition of computational basis state $|\mathds{1}\rangle$? It holds $|w\rangle-|\maths{1}=\alpha |A\rangle$

You can write any operator in any basis you want, if I understand your question correctly. Just replace $|A\rangle$ with whatever basis representation you want and $|A^{\perp}\rangle$ similarly.
